# Hiding an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to hide an element using jQuery, but I think I did something wrong. Please take a look at my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript"> 

$(function(){

function hide(id) { 
$("#"+id).hide();
}

});

hide("test");

</script>

<div id = "test"> Hello </div>
```

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP, Javascript uses `+`.

Comment: Your function must be outside the document.ready function

Comment: @aldrin27 But I thought all JQuery must go inside the document.ready function, to prevent codes from executing before the page is loaded.

Comment: Yes. But if that is a function it should be outside the ready function because if you include that inside it will also load the function.

Comment: @aldrin27 Really? I thought all functions are loaded whether they're inside or outside the ready function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sushil is right, but also, your "hide" function should be outside  the $() function and the call to it goes on the inside.  The whole thing looks like this:

```
function hide(id) {    
   $("#" + id).hide();
}

$(function(){
    hide("test");
});
```

Putting the hide() function inside of the $() makes it so you can only call it from inside of the $().  So, put it on the outside, and then you can call it from anywhere, including, from inside the $() part.

Comment: But I thought all JQuery must go inside the document.ready function, to prevent codes from executing before the page is loaded.

Comment: @jessica Function definitions aren't executed at the time they're defined, so they can be anywhere. What's important is that you don't call them until after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: @Jessica You should CALL the jQuery code from inside document.ready, but you can declare functions outside of it that you call from the document.ready part.  Make sense?

Comment: Ah. Ok. So you can define the function anywhere, even inside or outside of the document.ready function, but they must be CALLED inside of the document.ready function. Got you.

Comment: Yes, exactly... If you want, you can put them BOTH inside of document ready, but then the hide() function will only exist inside of that function, like a local variable would, which may be what you want...

Comment: Ah. So if I put them both inside the document.ready function, I can't call the hide() function in a different document.ready function. But if I put the hide() function outside of the document.ready function, I can use it in any other document.ready functions. I see. Good explanation. Btw, aldrin said that "But if that is a function it should be outside the ready function because if you include that inside it will also load the function." Is that true?

Comment: @jessica : I'm not sure what "load the function" means.  If they meant the function will exist and be usable inside of the document.ready, then yes.

Comment: But he's saying that it should always be outside of the document.ready function, because if it's on the inside it'll be loaded? I don't understand what he's saying either.

Answer (score 0):

your javascript code should be like

```
$(function() {

    function hide(id) {
        $("#" + id).hide(); // notice the '+'
    }

});
```

Comment: Obviously it has bugs, that's why he asked the question!

Comment: Does it have more than one bug? What are the others?

Comment: the first one is the curly braces and the second one is the concatenation operator

Comment: The third problem is that the call to `hide("test")` is outside of the function wrapper in which the hide function is declared, so it won't generate an error when called.

Comment: @jessica `hide("test");` should be inside the `document.ready`